# Always Check if there is Internet Connection Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing a xamarin forms app, i want to check every second if there is a internet connection, if the connection is lost, the program should go to diferent page.
I am using the plugin "Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" , but doesnt do what i want.
Is possible to do what i want?

Comment: the Connectivity plugin has events that will fire whenever the connectivity changes - how does this not fulfill your requirement?

Comment: I didnt know, i will check the documentation, like @Alessandro Caliaro did.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***Edit***: this can be easily done with the new [Xamarin Essentials Connectivity plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android), just follow the instructions there :D

Create a method in your App.cs (or App.xaml.cs) like this:

```
private async void CheckConnection()
{
    if(!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
         await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourPageWhenThereIsNoConnection());
    else
         return;
}
```

And use it on your main app method like this:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(seconds,
        () =>
        {
             CheckConnection();
        });
}
```

Comment: This kinda works, the Navigation isnt supported, how can naviagate to another page then?

Comment: @Phill Why not trying to use a popup instead a page?

Comment: I using the code above in my second page, instead of the app.cs, and now navigation with popup works fine.
Thanks alot.

Comment: @Phill , You can get that method using -> new NavigationPage().PushAsync(new YourPageWhenThereIsNoConnection())

Answer (score 11):

Never used, but this is a documentation about the plugin you are using

**Detecting Connectivity Changes**

Often you may need to notify your user or respond based on network changes. You can do this by subscribing several different events.

**Changes in Connectivity**

When any network connectivity is gained, changed, or loss you can register for an event to fire:

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler when connection changes
/// </summary>
event ConnectivityChangedEventHandler ConnectivityChanged; 
You will get a ConnectivityChangeEventArgs with the status if you are connected or not:

public class ConnectivityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
}

public delegate void ConnectivityChangedEventHandler(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e);
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
  {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Connectivity changed to {args.IsConnected}");
  };
```

**Changes in Connectivity Type**

When any network connectivity type is changed this event is triggered. Often it also is accompanied by a ConnectivityChanged event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler when connection type changes
/// </summary>
event ConnectivityTypeChangedEventHandler ConnectivityTypeChanged;
When this occurs an event will be triggered with EventArgs that have the most recent information:

public class ConnectivityTypeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ConnectionType> ConnectionTypes { get; set; }
}
public delegate void ConnectivityTypeChangedEventHandler(object sender, ConnectivityTypeChangedEventArgs e);
Example:

CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityTypeChanged += async (sender, args) =>
  {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Connectivity changed to {args.IsConnected}");
      foreach(var t in args.ConnectionTypes)
        Debug.WriteLine($"Connection Type {t}");
  };
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort to look into the existing tool they provided. Well done.