# Adding a ConnectivityChanged EventHandler to a class Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, event-handling

I am attempting to add an event handler to my xamarin forms project that will allow the app to detect network changes. To do this I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) tutorial and the Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged Event class. I have already added this requisite line of code to AssemblyInfo.cs per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) page:

```cs
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState)]
```

My code is as follows:

```cs
public partial class Main : TabbedPage
{
    public event EventHandler<ConnectivityChangedEventArgs> ConnectivityChanged;

    protected virtual void OnConnectivityChanged(ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<ConnectivityChangedEventArgs> handler = ConnectivityChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    static void HandleConnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A network change was detected");
    }

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ConnectivityChanged += HandleConnChange;
    }
}
```

There are no errors that appear in compilation or running the program, but when I turn the phone's internet off and back on it never hits the breakpoint I have set in HandleConnChange. How might I get this event handler working? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Replace `this.ConnectivityChanged` with `Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged`? Not answering because I cannot test right now. Just guessing.

Comment: you are creating a custom event but it is not tied to any underlying platform code that responds to a connectitvity change.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=ios

Comment: check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852164/always-check-if-there-is-internet-connection-xamarin-forms/46867158#46867158)